# Test database rows in separate Mocha tests

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Typical workflow with Mocha goes:

```
describe("my test", function(){
  it("should calculate X correctly", function(){...});
  it("should calculate Y correctly", function(){...});
  it("should calculate Z correctly", function(){...});
});
```

However, say I'm reading X, Y, and Z from a database where there could potentially be thousands of records. I definitely don't want to structure my test this way, or else I'd be reading every record once for each item:

```
describe("database test", function(){
  it("should calculate X correctly", function(){
    // check all X in the database
  });
  it("should calculate Y correctly", function(){
    // check all Y in the database
  });
  it("should calculate Z correctly", function(){
    // check all Z in the database
  });
});
```

Given Mocha's format, though, it would appear that this is the only way to test my database while retaining names for each test.

**Is there another way to test that would (a) label all tests correctly and (b) require each record to be read only once?**

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `before` hook to load all of the records, then access the same list of records within each test.

```
describe("database test", function () {
    var records = [];
    before(function (done) {
        // Load records into the variable "records"
        done();
    });

    it("should calculate X correctly", function () {
        // check all X in the database
    });
});
```

**Edit:** You can also [iterate](https://github.com/1602/jugglingdb/blob/33820ad8037fbaaff2d033e707bb9b1e0a1acdcc/test/manipulation.test.js#L265) through each record (assuming you're using jugglingdb or an ORM that supports it), without loading all records into memory:

```
describe("database test", function () {
    var someCalculation = 0;

    before(function (done) {
        // Only load 100 records at a time.
        Model.iterate({ batchSize: 100 }, function (singleObject, next, i) {
            // Do whatever you need to calculate x/y/z.
            someCalculation++;
            next();
        }, function (err) {
            // Callback
            done();
        }
    });

    it("should calculate X correctly", function (done) {
        // Validate/test here.
        someCalculation.should.be.above(1);
        done();
    });
});
```

You could iterate in each test, but since you only want to read each record once without retaining it in memory, loading it in the before hook should work best.

Comment: The problem is that it's thousands of records and I'm not certain they'd all fit in memory.

Comment: I edited the response. I'm still searching for a slightly better way to accomplish this though. Such as for every iteration, check all three `it("should...` methods.